# Rename Label and remove fields in shipping address onepage checkout - First Name -> Recipient Name etc

Tags: magento2

I am stuck in a clients requirement where I have to remove last name field and change label for First Name to Recipient Name & and few custom fields after First Name.

Comment: well which version is it?

Comment: Hope https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128579/57276 may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<item name="%the_component_to_be_disabled%" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Read more here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115826/magento-2-customising-checkout-page-not-working/115900#115900